# Access s3 bucket from different aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to restore a database as a part of our testing. The backups exists on the prod s3 account. My database is running as ec2 instance in dev account.

Can anyone tell me how can i access the prod s3 from dev account.

Steps:
 - i created a role on prod account and with trusted relationship with the dev account
 - i added a policy to the role.

{

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::prod/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

on dev account i created a role and with assume policy

```
> {   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/prod-role"
>     }   ] }
```

But i am unable to access the s3 bucket, can someone point me where i am wrong.
Also i added the above policy to an existing role. so does that mean its not working because of my instance profile ( inconsistent error)

Please help and correct me if i am wrong anywhere. I am looking for a solution in terms of a role and not as a user.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets recap: you want to access your prod bucket from the dev account.

There are two ways to do this, Method 1 is your approach however I would suggest Method 2:

**Method 1**: Use roles. This is what you described above, it's great, however, you cannot sync bucket to bucket if they're on different accounts as different access keys will need to be exported each time. You'll most likely have to sync the files from the prod bucket to the local fs, then from the local fs to the dev bucket.

How to do this:

Using roles, create a role on the production account that has access to the bucket. The trust relationship of this role must trust the role on the dev account that's assigned to the ec2 instance. Attach the policy granting access to the prod bucket to that role. Once that's all configured, the ec2 instance role in dev must be updated to allow `sts:AssumeRole` of that role you've defined in production. On the ec2 instance in dev you will need to run `aws sts assume-role --role-arn <the role on prod> --role-session-name <a name to identify the session>`. This will give you back 3 variables, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`. On your ec2 instance, run `set -a; AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${secret_access_key}; 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${access_key_id}; AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${session_token}`. Once those variables have been exported, you can run `aws sts get-caller-identity` and that should come back showing you that you're on the role you've provisioned in production. You should now be able to sync the files to the local system, and once that's done, unset the aws keys we set as env variables, then copy the files from the ec2 instance to the bucket in dev. Notice how there are two steps here to copy them? that can get quite annoying - look into method 2 on how to avoid this:

**Method 2:** Update the prod bucket policy to trust the dev account - this will mean you can access the prod bucket from dev and do a bucket to bucket sync/cp.
I would highly recommend you take this approach as it will mean you can copy directly between buckets without having to sync to the local fs.
To do this, you will need to update the bucket policy on the bucket in production to have a principals block that trusts the AWS account id of dev. An example of this is, update your prod bucket policy to look something like this:
NOTE: granting s3:* is bad, and granting full access to the account prob isnt suggested as anyone on the account with the right s3 permissions can now access this bucket, but for simplicity I'm going to leave this here:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example permissions",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::DEV_ACC_ID:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::PROD_BUCKET_NAME",
            "arn:aws:s3:::PROD_BUCKET_NAME/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Once you've done this, on the dev account, attach the policy in your main post to the dev ec2 instance role (the one that grants s3 access). Now when you connect to the dev instance, you do not have to export any environment variables, you can simply run `aws s3 ls s3://prodbucket` and it should list the files.
You can sync the files between the two buckets using `aws s3 sync s3://prodbucket s3://devbucket --acl bucket-owner-full-control` and that should copy all the files from prod to dev, and on top of that should update the ACLs of each file so that dev owns them (meaning you have full access to the files in dev).

Answer (score 1):

You need to assume the role in the production account from the dev account. Call `sts:AssumeRole` and then use the credentials returned to access the bucket.

You can alternatively add a bucket policy that allows the dev account to read from the prod account. You wouldn't need the cross account role in the prod account in this case.